# Подсчет количества символов в TextInput

Tags: python, kivy, textinputlayout

Если я в TextInput ввожу цифры, а потом их сразу или по одной удаляю, то TextInput не становиться пустой строкой и не показывает количество символов равным 0.

Как при удалении последнего символа (или всех сразу) получить длину строки 0?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        self.txt = TextInput()
        self.txt.bind(text=self.on_focusa)
        bl.add_widget(self.txt)
        self.lab = Label()
        bl.add_widget(self.lab)

        return bl

    def on_focusa(self, instance, value):
        try:
            txt = int(self.txt.text)*2
            self.lab.text = str(txt)
            print(len(str(txt)))
        except ValueError:
            pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что когда вы удаляете все знаки из текстового поля, то значение value не приходит в on_focusa, функция не отрабатывает так, как вам бы хотелось.

Такой код может решить проблему, его можно оптимизировать если вынести повторяющийся код в отдельную функцию:

```
    def on_focusa(self, instance, value):
    if value: # Проверяем значение value
        try:
            txt = int(self.txt.text)*2
            self.lab.text = str(txt)
            print(len(str(txt)))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    else: # Если value отсутствует, то выводим нули
        txt = 0
        self.lab.text = str(txt)
        print(len(str(txt)))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Поправил на txt = '' и получил то что требуется